# Bulma: align form horizontal fields across columns

Tags: html, css, forms, bulma

I'm trying to build a form which is divided in two columns in the top portion, and one column for the bottom portion, similar to what is shown in this image:

[image]

I created a template using Bulma columns, but the fields are not aligning the way I want them to. Below is a sample code I've been playing with:

```
  <section class="section">
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">

        <div class="field is-horizontal has-background-danger">
          <div class="field-label is-small">
              <label class="label">Info 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="field-body">
              <div class="field">
                  <div class="control">
                      <input type="text" class="textarea is-small" placeholder="Some text here...">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="column">

      <div class="field is-horizontal has-background-warning">
        <div class="field-label is-small">
            <label class="label">Info 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" class="textarea is-small" placeholder="Some text here...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="field is-horizontal has-background-primary">
      <div class="field-label is-small">
          <label class="label">Info 0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
              <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" class="textarea is-small" placeholder="Some text here...">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

And this is what I'm getting
[image]

What I'd like to achieve instead is the following:
[image]

Does anybody know how can I fix this? I'm not really experienced doing CSS or web in general. Please feel free to suggest a different layout if you think this is not a good design.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">

        <div class="columns"  style="margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px">
          <div class="column" style="margin-right: 5px">

            <div class="field is-horizontal columns">
              <div class="column is-2 is-small has-background-danger">
                  <label class="label">Info 1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="field-body">
                  <div class="field">
                      <div class="control">
                          <input type="text" class="textarea is-small" placeholder="Some text here...">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="column" style="margin-left: 5px">

          <div class="field is-horizontal columns"  >
            <div class="column is-2 is-small has-background-warning">
                <label class="label">Info 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="field-body">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="textarea is-small" placeholder="Some text here...">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

        </div>



        <div class="field is-horizontal columns" style="margin: 5px;">
          <div class="column is-1 is-small has-background-primary">
              <label class="label">Info 0</label>
          </div>
          <div class="field-body">
              <div class="field">
                  <div class="control">
                      <input type="text" class="textarea is-small" placeholder="Some text here...">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```